# NuGet add reference error--- fail to installi packages

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Thanks for checking out my question. I know it has been already asked in Stackoverflow but the answers could not solve my problem, so I have to flag here and wait for your help.

I am using Win10 sys. Visual Studio 2013. The trouble is, I could not install MySQL packet to my visual studio. According to some answers, I cleared the package cache, but still failed. The error msg is:

[image]

Please feel free to advice.

Comment: which .net framework version you are targeting ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project in solution explorer and select "**Manage NuGet Packages..**".

1) Check which version of the *Google.Protobuf* package you have and remove it from your project.

2) Retry to install your *MySql.Data* package.

3) Then check if the version of *Google.Protobuf* installed with your *MySql.Data* is ok compared to the old one. If necessary, use the Package Manager to upgrade the *Google.Protobuf* package to the last recent version.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Maxwell77. I checked out the installed packages from 'Manage NuGet Packages' on my Visual Studio. It turns out that 'No packages are installed in the current solution'. So I guess Google.Protobuf is actually is not installed on my Visual Studio.

Comment: Really curious, check your packages.config file to remove the Google.Protobuf reference to allow the MySQL.Data package installation.

Comment: sorry could you please enlighten me where I can find 'Packages.config'? I looked around but failed to see it.

Comment: I think the cause is the .Net framework version is not compatible to MySQL version as in I got an error msg 'Install-Package : Could not install package 'MySql.Data 8.0.11'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly ' after I upgraded NuGet version. But problem still has not been solved because the versions are not ok with each other.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add all the different versions of package you have or want to install and which part of your project depends on another version of Google.Protobuf and which version ?